How to show logs in Laravel Telescope
I cannot get the logs to be saved into the telescope_entries table, so that Telescope shows them.
Action:
Log::channel('telescope')->debug('testing log:', ['variable' => $this->testVar]);

in config/logging.php I have the channel defined:
'telescope' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => FingersCrossedHandler::class,
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

In TelescopeServiceProvider.php I have added the LOG type to the filter:
public function register(): void
    {
        Telescope::night();

        $this->hideSensitiveRequestDetails();

        $isLocal = $this->app->environment('local');
               
        Telescope::filter(function (IncomingEntry $entry) use ($isLocal) {
                        
            return $isLocal ||
                $entry->isReportableException() ||
                $entry->isFailedRequest() ||
                $entry->isFailedJob() ||
                $entry->isScheduledTask() ||
                $entry->hasMonitoredTag() ||
                $entry->type === EntryType::LOG;
        });
    }

I am getting errors like:
laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [telescope] is not defined.

What am I missing?

Telescope panel displays data defined in Telescope filters. For log and all request entries, simply add the following condition to the filter:
Telescope::filter(function (IncomingEntry $entry) use ($isLocal) {           
            return $isLocal ||
                $entry->isReportableException() ||
                $entry->isFailedRequest() ||
                $entry->isFailedJob() ||
                $entry->isScheduledTask() ||
                $entry->hasMonitoredTag() ||
 
                $entry->isLog() ||
                $entry->isRequest()||
        });

